# replicate specific data between 2 mysql databases

Tags: mysql, synchronization, replication

I'm trying to replicate data between 2 MySQL databases. The issue is only *some* rows needs to be transferred to the second MySQL server based on a specific criteria.

I have 2 MySQL servers. The first one is intranet only, there is an application that *reads/writes* to it. The second MySQL server is online and the application connecting to it is *read only*.

I need to find a way to get the data from the first server to the second based on specific criteria (some rows are labeled as private and should not synchronized). I tried to do it with a trigger on the first server (trigger on insert/update) but I have way too many tables, it's very time consuming to do it like that.

What approaches do I have? dumping the entire data is not an option as there will a lot of records and the online server cannot afford to go offline just to get the information. Add to that that not all the records are for public usage.

Comment: do you need data to be synched real time or you can bear a few minutes offset ?

Answer (score 0):

1 - disable replication 
2 - on the intranet, create an empty database and a view based on a query that shows exactly the rows you want to replicate to your internet server
3 - replicate the new database (the one containing the view) to a new database on your internet server
4 - on your internet server, you can cron a script that inserts the new rows to your desired table table, think about using dumps and LOAD DATA IN FILE, it should go verry quickly.